# How do I implement a floating label to a dynamically created edittext in android?

Tags: java, android

This is how I am dynamically creating my edittext element:

```
EditText myEditText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

myEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-smallcaps", Typeface.NORMAL));

myEditText.setText(arr.get(0).get(0));

parent.addView(myEditText);
```

Right now my edittext looks like this:

[image],

whereas I want it to be like this:

[image]

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you can follow to create Floating Label EditText dynamically:

Create `EditText` and set layout, styles and hint on it

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-smallcaps", Typeface.NORMAL));
editText.setText(arr.get(0).get(0));
editText.setHint("Floating Label"); // replace text with required label text
editText.setPadding(45,30,45,30); // replace padding as per your requirements
editText.setBackground(null); // This allows TextInputLayout to set the EditText 's background to an outlined or filled box
```

Create `TextInputLayout` with some properties

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
textInputLayout.setHintEnabled(true);
textInputLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
```

Attach border outlined theme to `TextInputLayout`

```
textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
```

Add `EditText` to the `TextInputLayout`

```
textInputLayout.addView(editText);
```

Finally add the `TextInputLayout` to the `parent` view

```
parent.addView(textInputLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

The design that you have mentioned is not of edit text but of *TextInputLayout*
and inside it *TextInputEditText* is present. You can create like this in XML

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

or programmatically

```
 TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      EditText myEditText  = new EditText(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

    myEditText.setTextSize(16);
    myEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    myEditText.setHint("hint");
    myEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));

    textInputLayout.addView(myEditText, editTextParams);
```

Comment: How do I create the `textInputLayout` programatically?